# Refreshing a DataGridView set up in the designer

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I saw this question asked a million times and none of the answers looked right. I hope someone can help me.

I have a `DataGridView` with a `TableAdapter`, `BindingSource` and `DataSet` objects all created from the designer.

All I want to do is simply reload the data from the database since I change it by another way, and I cannot find any solution to this.

Comment: Could you post a link to at least few of those millions?

Comment: Yes! Here's one where there are a bunch of  workaround like solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253843/simple-datagridview-refresh-question, no answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481636/datagridview-update, no answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326987/update-access-database-with-datagridview so on, i dunno i searched in google for 15 mins and found this refill method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way myself, hope it helps others, and If you know a better way feel free to correct me:

```
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSource.TableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [BindingSource.ResetBindings Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx)

Comment: yes, it doesn't do it. It doesn't read the data from the database, only refreshes the control with the client side data I guess..

Comment: I didn't tried it, but I found this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt.aspx